# How to get IntelliJ IDEA run configuration to make use of Maven filtered resources?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I'm having some trouble working out how to run a project in IntelliJ IDEA that makes use of Maven resource filtering.

In my `src/main/resources` directory I have

1. `spring.xml` file that is used to start the application
2. `service.env.properties`

I also have the following in `src/main/filters`

1. `env-uat.properties`
2. `env-prd.properties`
3. `env-dev.properties`

In my `pom.xml` file I use `maven-resources-plugin` to create three configuration directories that get included into the final package. Each one is based on one of the filers. This package can then be deployed on any of the three environments without having to be rebuilt.

The issue that I'm having is when I try to run this using IntelliJ IDEA run configs I have to use

```
-Xbootclasspath/a:target/config/dev;
```

to force IntelliJ IDEA to pick up the `.properties` file with the correct filter.

While this works it doesn't seem like it is the right way to go here. Does anyone have any advice on how to handle configuration for multiple environments and how to get IntelliJ IDEA to pick this up through run configurations.

Comment: My question: **(1)** Why don't put all `*.properties` to `resources` directory? **(2)** What is your version of Spring? **(3)** How to tell Maven you are using `uat`, `prd` or `dev` profile?

Comment: I had this problem - fixed it by amending the Maven plug-in configuration.  The other thing that might be happening to you is the IntelliJ artifact isn't set up and built using Maven.  Run the Maven lifecycle and tie the IntelliJ build to run it.

Comment: /filters isn't in your /resources.  Put those .properties files in /resources and map them during build.

Comment: @DoNhuVy I could include all the properties files in the resources directory but the deployment process creates a symlink to the correct directory. I don't want to change this as it's standard across the departments processes.

Comment: I have found a quick solution. Adding a second file to the property placeholder config that I know will only be present in local

`location="classpath:service.env.properties,classpath:service.local.propertie`
`code`